# IOS : Button click not getting registered, xcode not showing code and storyboard in parallel

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am trying out some IOS programming and building a basic app from documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1). I followed the documentation, but image click is not getting registered as I have added a print statement also inside. I am trying out code in simulator, if that's the problem.

Screenshot :

[image]

The image I am clicking is a screenshot.

Code :

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TestApplication
//
//  Created by  on 28/04/16.
//  Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var mealName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    // MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // Hide the keyboard
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true

    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        mealName.text=textField.text
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        nameTextField.delegate=self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

    // WHen the user cancels the selection of image
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        // The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the original.
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
        photoImageView.image = selectedImage

        // Dismiss the picker.
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Button clicked to open library")
        // Hide the keyboard.
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

        // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Button clicked");
    }




}
```

The print message is not displayed when the image is clicked.

Also, in the documentation, when I click the layout buttons, I should be able to see the code in the same window with UI on side, but that's not happening. I require it for creating outlets. Any help would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: Is your button connected with action?

Comment: @BhavinRamani : It's photoImageView, which is there in the class. How can I verify it?

Comment: In storyboard right click on button and can you see any events connected?

Comment: @BhavinRamani : I see this : http://s32.postimg.org/fl04ju45h/Screen_Shot_2016_05_13_at_13_11_00.png    . Also, if I drag and drop photo in it, then the gallery opens.

Comment: @BhavinRamani : The problem is not with the button, if you check the tutorial link I have given in main post, the image is to be clicked, I added a Tap gesture to the image.  But I have to drag drop to open photos, and after selecting photo from the gallery, it is not getting set in the image-view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111853/discussion-between-bhavin-ramani-and-we-are-borg).

Comment: set tap gesture  to imageview because it it not button and set imageview to set user interaction to yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad()` add this line:

```
photoImageView.userInteractionEnabled=true
```